# java JMathPlot or Plot2DPanel

Tags: java

I have a client and server, I can send data to the server but I need help on how I can use the data received from the client to draw a graph using Plot2DPanel/JMathPlot. a simple code on how I can assign data received from the client to Plot2DPanel. I have the code below, which receives data from the client but I don't how can I use this on Plot2DPanel.

```
while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for the incoming mesages" +portNumber+ "....");
            receiveSocket.receive(receivedPacket);

            IAddress address = receivedPacket.getAddress();
            int clientPort = receivedPacket.getPort();
            String message = new String(receivedPacket.getData());

            message = message.trim();
            System.out.println("The message {+mesage+}.\n\t\t The message is received from host: " +IAddress+ "on port" + portNumber);

            byte[] sendData = new byte[256];
            String sendBackMessage = "Thank you, message was received";
            sendData = sendBackMessage.getBytes();

            receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IAddress, clientPort);
            receiveSocket.send(receivedPacket);
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i just added part of my server code, which receives data from the client.

Comment: Seeing an example of what your server is receiving as data would help greatly, as it's what you're asking us to put on a `Plot2DPanel`